# Ubuntu 14.04LTS updated, mysql wont start (HY000/2002, mysql command not found errors)

Tags: 14.04, mysql, database

While there is a number of answers for this question already, I haven't managed to fix this issue with any of them. So here are my facts.

I updated Ubuntu 14.04 after about 2 months of non usage.
Right after the update, mysql would not work, giving me the following errors

PHP (local web dev):

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory
```

Console:

```
sudo service mysql start  
start: Job failed to start
```

or (not as root)

```
service mysql start
start: Unknown job: mysql
```

MySQL installation check gives me:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql
libapache2-mod-auth-mysql           install
libmysqlclient18:amd64              install
libmysqlclient18:i386               install
libqt4-sql-mysql:i386               install
mysql-common                        install
mysql-server-5.5                    deinstall
mysql-workbench-community           install
php5-mysql                          deinstall
php7.0-mysql                        install
```

I see that while mysql-server-5.5 is installed, some other packages are missing, but from what I have read so far these are not necessary for the server to run.

Also, trying to get the server status using mysqladmin will return:

```
$ mysqladmin -u root -p status
mysqladmin: command not found
```

I have also tried to change the mysql data directory's permissions, as I have read that root perms may prohibit access and start of mysql server, although that should not be a consideration since mysql is not even recognized as a command.

I would have no problem trying to reinstall mysql if I knew my databases would be left in place.

UPDATE

I also tried dmesg command, and I get this result

```
dmesg | grep mysql
[    4.315790] init: Failed to spawn mysql main process: unable to execute: No such file or directory
[ 3556.147153] audit: type=1400 audit(1482506149.514:64): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=4942 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 3556.149528] init: Failed to spawn mysql main process: unable to execute: No such file or directory
[ 4666.027886] audit: type=1400 audit(1482507259.370:65): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=5724 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 4666.030250] init: Failed to spawn mysql main process: unable to execute: No such file or directory
[ 8341.035215] audit: type=1400 audit(1482510934.298:66): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=7776 comm="apparmor_parser"
[ 8341.046625] init: Failed to spawn mysql main process: unable to execute: No such file or directory
```

Apparently mysqld is missing(?)

```
locate mysqld
```

returns

```
/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld
/etc/apparmor.d/cache/usr.sbin.mysqld
/etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.sbin.mysqld
/etc/mysql/conf.d/mysqld_safe_syslog.cnf
/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/mysqldump
```

Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-backup.html), I noticed that you can (?) actually copy the data files and move them back to the new installation (Cold Backup). So I just copied the files and moved on and installed MySQL 5.6.

Moving the files turned out to be unnecessary in my occasion, as the databases were all in place after the installation.